# Best encoding setting for presentation like video

Tags: encoding, youtube, transcoding, 4k

I have a video series that have a low fps by nature. The videos are in presentation format with audio.

The video is produced using Adobe Premiere Pro CC 2015 and contains 4K image clips and 256kbps audio clips. Videos range from 2 minutes to 4 hours.

The 1 minute video is around 274MB and the 4 hours video is around 60GB although most of the video is still pictures.  Is there a way to render the video with a smaller size?

Here is a sample of the video series:

Comment: What is the intended distribution channel?

Comment: You may also find https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/10418/what-is-the-optimal-codec-and-encoding-parameters-to-encode-video-podcast/ useful.

Comment: I intend to distribute via YouTube and need 2K to make it look nice on TVs.

Comment: Which encoding do you use now? MPEG should be fine I think.